# Access - input value dependes on a select box

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in access with several fields.
now, lets say a I have a table called TEAMS, which contains team's size, name and id.
now, I have a form with a select box, which shows the teams names, and under the select box I want to have a text field which shows the team's size of each team, dependes what you choosed on the select box.

for example: I you select team A, with 10 members, you'll se 10 in the text field, if you changed it to team B, with 8 members now the text field will show you 8.

If I had to do it with PHP and SQL I would do something like:
SELECT `team_size` FROM `TEAMS` WHERE `team_id` = `my_form.team_select_box`

and then print those results with JS on the html form... but I am new to ms access and I have no idea how to it...

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `AfterUpdate()` event to you drop down. Your dropdown needs to have two columns. One for the ID and one for the team name. Within the `AfterUpdate` event you can execute your sql to identify the team size as you described in your question. Then set the value of the text box to the result.

This code will work for an AfterUpdate procedure in form with a dropdown called `scltTeam` and a text box called `txtSize`.

```
Private Sub slctTeam_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim id As Integer

    id = Me!slctTeam.Value
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Team WHERE ID = " & id
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    Me!txtSize.Value = rst!Size
End Sub
```